# QtCreator plugins and templates missing

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qt, qt-creator

I just downloaded the Ubuntu phone SDK and QT creator according to [the instructions](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/).

When I fire up QTCreator, I get a screen as shown

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HrgO1su.png?1]

If I ignore this message and hit continue, there are no templates to create the Mobile application as indicated in the tutorial I'm following.

---

I tried installing qt5-default and qtchooser - problem still persists. Here is the error message

```
Cannot load plugin because dependency failed to load: RemoteLinux(2.6.82) 
Reason: Cannot load plugin because dependency failed to load: QtSupport(2.6.82) 
Reason: Cannot load plugin because dependency failed to load: ProjectExplorer(2.6.82) 
Reason: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qtcreator/plugins/QtProject/libProjectExplorer.so: 
Cannot load library /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qtcreator/plugins/QtProject/libProjectExplorer.so: 
(libQt5Declarative.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: what happens if you try to install qt5-default and qtchooser? could you also paste Full error somewhere I can not read the last couple of lines

Comment: Have you really installed Gt5 from the `canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper` PPA as described [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/#step-get-toolkit)? What QtCreator version do you have?

Comment: Try installing libbotan-1.10-0, it seems they forgot to add this as a dependency in the package..

Comment: @Cantormath How would that package change anything?

Comment: I followed Octavian's reply ... Followed the instruction on the PPA link. Terminal showed a message : 0 installed, 0 updated...then software centre showed some 28 updates .. I went ahead and updated - restarted the computer and BAM ! it worked ! thank you to everybody for contributing ...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem earlier today when I updated my system and opened QT Creator. I found that the the ubuntu-sdk package didn't update itself properly. Try running this command to fix the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk notepad-qml
```

I am sure you already ran this to initially install QT Creator, but running this again helped me. I cannot guarantee this will fix the issue, it worked for me.

Hope this helps!

---

Plus run this as well:

```
sudo apt-get install libbotan*
```

Comment: nope, this did not work for me :(... I'm going to try CMDann's method now ...

Comment: did not work for me...

Answer (score 1):

As David mentioned rerunning this command seemed to help:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk notepad-qml
```

The only other thing for me was I had to remove the previous install first and run another update before reinstalling would work.

To uninstall run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-sdk notepad-qml
```

Then update the sources and reinstall the packages.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk notepad-qml
```

I am running 12.10 so I don't know if this is the same for each release.

Comment: Hey, I'm new with all this ... how can I uninstall the neccessary tools ?

Comment: You can either remove packages from the software centre or run the command in the terminal `sudo apt-get remove {package-name}`