# no ubuntu touch templates in qt 5.0.2

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qt, qt-creator, ubuntu-sdk

I have been using qt for some time now (lastly Qt 4.8), writing some desktop apps. Now I wanted to try doing something on ubuntu touch and so I installed the Ubuntu SDK.

What I did was uninstall my regular Qt version that I had (so as not to create any conflict) and ran the sdk ppa

everything installed fine it seemed. No errors warnings or dependencies issues and I indeed have a qt Creator with the Ubuntu SDK. Also I now have version 5.0.2 so all seems fine. Except i do not have any kind of Ubuntu touch templates. Only the Qt desktop templates.

I am running a Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit machine.

As a test, I installed the Ubuntu sdk on a virtual(Box) Machine (64 bit Ubuntu 13.04) and here I do have the Ubuntu touch templates installed. (Note: I dont want to run it in a Virtual environment as there are OpenGL issues in VirtualBox which causes qmlscene to crash, but that is another issue).

Also: I am aware of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313879/problem-with-qtcreator-after-update) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259363/qtcreator-plugins-and-templates-missing) issue and they do not resolve things.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I could sure use some pointers on how to troubleshoot this. Atm I have no idea where to start. I did an apt-get purge and autoremove nad reinstalled but this too did nothing. I am hjust not getting any project templates for Ubuntu touch..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your installation is hit by an old and strange QtCreator bug:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1164504

The workaround is to remove the old configuration of the QtCreator and restart the QtC:

rm -r .config/Trolltech.conf .config/Qt* .config/Nokia*

Comment: right on the money! thanks I never would have foundthisone myself :)